# libusb-1.0 write rights for generic usb device

Tags: c, linux, libusb-1.0

I'm programming in C with Anjuta a small application with libusb library.

libusb has need the write rights for some purpose.
This argoment was already dealt in this topic: "Get access to USB device on Linux (libusb-1.0)?".
Maybe the topic solution work fine (I'm not tried yet) but i would like my application access to all usb device and not to the specific one.
i've tried to set a suid bit at a libusb-1.0.so file which have a root owner but libusbopen function, for example, answer "libusb requires write access to USB device nodes" again.
I don't wont to build the entire anjuta project as root user but so far this is the only solution for this libusb-1.0 issue.

Is there a solution for get write access to inode of a general usb device (for example hot plug pendrive) without modify udev behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. Maybe it's not good but it seems to work well.
I have added a permission rules file (`020_permissions.rules`) in the **udev** configuration directory (`/etc/udev/rules.d`) where the unique rule is which Unix group should own all the USB device nodes.

The file content is:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", GROUP=="group to belong my user"
```

I hope this helps you if you have a similar libusb issue.